# KDF and PRF in GlobaPlatform SCP 03

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I want to implement Globalplatform SCP 03 protocol in javacard. The main problem is KDF and PRF implementation in card. I have three question:

1. Is there any opensource implementation of KDF and PRF in javacard?
2. I found "RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM);". there is 3 and 4 input for PRF function in NIST sp 800-108, but i can set only one parameter for RandomData in javacard (only seed). is it implementation of PRF?
3. Does PRF with same inputs, generates same result in different execution? if answer is no, why card and host can generate same session keys by using it?

Thank you very much.

Mohsen

Answer (score 2):

> I want to implement Globalplatform SCP 03 protocol in javacard

That's nice, but you know that you can already use the secure messaging channel though the Global Platform API, right? So you would only do this if you would like an identical channel after personalization of the card. It may of course be that your particular card only supports the old 3DES based protocols.

> Is there any opensource implementation of KDF and PRF in javacard?

Well, not a KDF, but constructing a KDF from a PRF isn't that hard. And of PRF's there are a few already included: any MAC is a PRF, including [HMAC-SHA1](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html#ALG_HMAC_SHA1). However, GP SCP 03 uses [AES CMAC](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/security/Signature.html#ALG_AES_CMAC_128) with specific input parameters as KDF.

Basically a hash function or MAC is a poor mans KDF without the input parameters explicitly specified. But for that you read the Global Platform specifications.

> I found "RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM);". there is 3 and 4 input for PRF function in NIST sp 800-108, but i can set only one parameter for RandomData in javacard (only seed). is it implementation of PRF?

No, a seeded PRNG is not a PRF and you can only **add** seed info to most implementations, not re-seed the PRNG completely. But again, you need a specific KDF: AES-CMAC, not any kind of KDF for SCP 03.

> Does PRF with same inputs, generates same result in different execution? if answer is no, why card and host can generate same session keys by using it?

Yes, of course it does, as long as it doesn't have a random *state* in the first place, like the random number generators. A *non-determinstic* PRF would be pretty useless.

Comment: Thank you Maartan for your reply. I access smartcards which support GP 2.1.1 , SCP 01 and SCP 02. In previous version of my applet, it was supporting SecureMessaging with SCP 01 and 02. So it uses 3DES2Key obsolete algorithm and it didn't support R-Mac and R-ENC. Now i want to use AES and R-MAC and R-ENC. Can i use GP 2.2 library in GP 2.1.1 cards?

Comment: I found GlobalPlatformPro project that implementing scp 03 and AESCMAC128 implementation in following link: https://pastebin.com/JQ9xQ5vK.  As i see in GlobalPlatforpro, scp03_kdf uses constant, context, blocklen_bits and label as input. does these values have to concatenate to each other as AESCMAC128 input buffer?

Comment: First comment: no, obviously not (although the API itself hasn't changed as far as I know, just the implementation beneath it and maybe a few constants and such). Second commment: the Global Platform specifications with a separate addendum for SCP 03 *are available for free*. Try and read/understand the standard first before continuing. If unsure *read the standard*.